# Криво отображается TextView в Samsung S4

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                  android:id="@+id/refresh"
                                                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                  tools:context="com.shppandroid1.app.MainActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/orangeBg_700"
                android:gravity="center">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/choose_category"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorMainTextWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_title_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/library_recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему в Samsung Galaxy S4 TextView в ActionBar уехал в лево? Есть ли какие то догадки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В теме: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270652/weird-behavior-with-a-relativelayout-and-the-galaxy-s4 намекают что почему-то в S4 `gravity` некорректно работает в `RelativeLayout` и советуют переместить элемент который выравнивается в `LinearLayout`, где и использовать `gravity`.